# Angular router prefix

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular2-routing

I have a bunch of components that use router with absolute paths for navigation on some actions.

Lets consider i have the EntityComponent
with some action that navigates to /otherEntity/* urls

That works fine.

For now i added another one top level component and configured the router with the following url: 
localhost/PREFIX/ to target that component, also i added the existing routes as the childs.

I can access the existing components by the localhost/prefix/entities but the navigation of this components is broken. When i perform actions i navigated to /otherEntity/ instead of /prefix/otherEntity

Is there any way to solve it? I use relative paths for some of the components when i can, but there are some cases when i can't do that way.

Main routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
          {
            path: '',
            component: AppComponent,
            children: [
              applicationRoutes
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'prefix/',
            component: AppPrefixComponent,
            children: [
              applicationRoutes
            ],
          },
]
```

Application lvl routes:

```
export const applicationRoutes: Routes = 
    [
            {
              path: 'entities',
              component: EntityComponent
            },
            {
              path: 'anotherEntity',
              component: AnotherEntityComponent,
            },
    ]
```

Navigation sample:

```
export class EntityComponent {

   navigateToAnotherEntity() {
      this.router.navigate('/anotherEntity');
   }
}
```

Comment: share us some code. Its hard to comment without any code

Comment: I've updated the question, hope its clear now

Comment: are you tried to build or run your project with the base href `ng (serve | build) --baseHref=prefix`?

Comment: I have not tried, also i have to preserve the default routes (without prefix) too

Comment: Please try to use the above example, I think it can help you? Please let me know about the results.

Comment: Well, that works, but i have to preserve the access to the pages without the prefix too.
Also, the path of the url a bit more complicated. Its like /prefix/:someParam

Comment: and what about tu change the applicationRoutes to the function which will be take the prefix as argument and return the routes array?

Comment: which depends on the argument will be insert the prefix into each route data?

Comment: well, there are no issues with applicationRoutes. They work like expected. I can navigate to /prefix/entities.
There are issues with the navigation of the components, like navigateToAnotherEntity of the EntityComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean something like this

```
export function applicationRoutes(prefix: string = ''): Routes {
  return  [
            {
              path: 'entities',
              component: EntityComponent,
              data: {prefix: prefix}
            },
            {
              path: 'anotherEntity',
              component: AnotherEntityComponent,
              data: {prefix: prefix}
            },
    ]
}
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
          {
            path: '',
            component: AppComponent,
            children: [
                 applicationRoutes('')
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'prefix/',
            component: AppPrefixComponent,
            children: [
              applicationRoutes('prefix')
            ],
          },
]
```

and in component.ts
you can get the data from router

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
prefix = ''
constrcutor(private router: Router) {
   this.prefix = this.router.snapshot.data['prefix']
}
   navigateToAnotherEntity() {
      this.router.navigate(`${this.prefix}/anotherEntity`);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you too, Glad to help you! @TorSen